# Unable to load Angular templates cross-domain with custom headers in requests

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, templates

we have a project for a client that consists of 3 different websites, and we wanted to re-use as much code as possible. We have one project that contains the bulk of the core Angular JavaScript / templates for directives etc.

We are using ASP.NET 4 and Angular 1.5.5.

I am able to render out a template that's held in Project 1 from Project 2 using the absolute URL with CORS enabled.

However, we are also using a request interceptor for authentication for Single-Sign-On between applications, using the request headers. This stops the cross-domain templates from being pulled over into Project 2 with the following error: 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44302/path/to/template.html. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`.

If I remove the code that is setting an 'Authorization' header, the template works perfectly cross-domain.

It looks like the only difference in the request **with** the interceptor is it has the following headers:

`access-control-request-headers:authorization
 access-control-request-method:GET`

Could this be causing the template to not be loaded?

Comment: How have you enabled CORS ?

Comment: Hi, this has been resolved, I just posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by setting up CORS in the ASP.NET web side instead of the Angular side.

We enabled it in the Startup.cs file with a private method. We have a Web.config setting called `Cors.AllowedOrigins` which contains a `;` separated string with each application we want to allow in CORS.

```
    private void EnableCors(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cors.AllowedOrigins"];
        if (origins != null)
        {
            foreach (var origin in origins.Split(';'))
            {
                policy.Origins.Add(origin);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
        }

        var corsOptions = new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
            }
        };
        app.UseCors(corsOptions);
    }
```

And we called this in the Configuration method, passing the `IAppBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the header makes the browser make a preflight OPTIONS request, and the server returns a 405 for that OPTIONS request. The browser then aborts the "real" request. Only simple requests can be made without the need of this preflight request. You can only use a [limited set of headers to qualify as simple request](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)

If you can serve the template on the same domain and port, it will not be a CORS request and this preflight request will not be made. If not, you can send the correct response to the OPTIONS request using [this guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. We have tried following the guide and tried many things to no avail. In the Web.Config for Project 1 (which we are trying to pull html from) I have allowed `*` for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, I have allowed all Methods and the following for Headers: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />`. in the JS for Project 2 I have tried adding the 3 Access-Control headers matching the config but no dice.